# return more than one element with XQuery: output repetition

Tags: xml, xquery, zorba

I have a xsd file. For every xs:element inside xs:sequence, I want to convert them to `<Class></Class>`. So for this file below, the output should contain 3 times of `<Class></Class>`.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="contacts">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="contact"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="contact">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:NCName"/>
        <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:NCName"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="citizen" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But instead I got this:

```
$ zorba -i -f -q test.xqy
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Class/>
<Class/>
```

This output looks so strange. I dont have `<Class/>` in the xqy file.

xqy file:

```
for $x in doc("test.xsd")/xs:schema/xs:element/xs:complexType/xs:sequence
return <Class>
  </Class>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML, `<Class></Class>` and `<Class/>` are equivalent nodes with mere serialization differences. Your XQuery processor is removing the whitespace between `<Class>` and `</Class>`. You could try setting serialization options for the processor, or added `<Class xml:space="preserve">`.

Comment: I dont even understand what 'serialization' is. why is it so hard to just repeat displaying some kind of string in XQuery. To me <Class></Class> could be simply taken as string.

Comment: @JACKM "To me <Class></Class> could be simply taken as string" then you haven't begun to understand the concepts of the language. XQuery doesn't manipulate markup as strings, it manipulates trees of nodes, and in XQuery `<Class></Class>` is an expression which, when evaluated, creates an element node named `Class`.

Comment: Thx dude. Could you recommend an advanced tutorial other than the specification?

Answer (score 0):

You could improve the XPath part with `/*` because you are searching for children of the `xs:sequence`:

XQuery 3.0

```
for $x in doc("test.xsd")/xs:schema/xs:element/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/*
return <Class></Class>
```

With this I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Class/>
<Class/>
<Class/>
```